# Django serving static files even with Debug off and no web server set to serve

Tags: python, django

Based on all I've read in the docs and on various s/o questions, Django cannot serve static files in production (when `DEBUG = False`) and they have to be served by a web server. Yet, when I run my code my static files are showing up just fine even with debug turned off. This concerns because as we move to production, I can't imagine it will continue to serve those files without me setting it up so they're served by a web server and I don't want my dev environment to not give me an accurate picture of how it will work in production.

How is it possible that my app is serving static files without a web server with `DEBUG = False`? I've included the relevant blurbs in my `settings.py` file, `urls.py` file, and my command to `collectstatic` in my Dockerfile. It also serves the static files just fine when I have `RUN python manage.py collectstatic` and `STATIC_ROOT` commented out.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
                  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STAT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**settings.py**

```
STAT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STAT]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'prod_static')
```

**Dockerfile**

```
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/deployment/

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 2):

Django is serving all contents of 'static' folder because of this definition:

```
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STAT)
```

The command `collectstatic` does not need this definition, as it searches for all folders present in `STATICFILES_DIRS` and copies all static assets to your `STATIC_ROOT`.

Also, you should change this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STAT)
```

Like this, on development you are serving `static` folder with django and on production you will need a web server to serve `prod_static` folder.

Comment: But even when I comment out `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STAT)` it still serves the files. Also, I'm not totally clear on how you recommend I should change that excerpt.

Comment: Check what settings your `manage.py` is using.
About the change, please notice the `settings.STAT` instead of `settings.STATIC_ROOT`